# EditText which starts only numeric number 8 or 9

Tags: android

May i know how to input numeric values that starts only 8 or 9 because this edit text is for user to input their handphone numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You'll have to use a TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to read each character that is typed in to your EditText and determine if it is valid.

So in your case just make a if statement that checks to see if the EditText is empty (and thus what they are entering will be the first character) then check to see if they entered an 8 or a 9, if so put it into the EditText, if not discard it and maybe give them a note saying that they must enter 8 or 9